# Masstransit (non-DI) configuration to autogenerate an Azure Service Bus Topic with Duplicate Detection enabled

Tags: masstransit

I've discovered no Masstransit configuration that allows a service bus Topic to be created with Duplicate Detection enabled.

You can do it with Queues simply enough. But for Topics it seems a bit of a mystery.

Does anybody have a working sample?

Perhaps it is not possible.

I've been trying to use the IServiceBusBusFactoryConfigurator provided by the Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus method.

I'd thought that some use of IServiceBusBusFactoryConfigurator.Publish method and IServiceBusBusFactoryConfigurator.SubscriptionEndpoint method would accomplish the task, but after a myriad of trials I've come up with no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure your message type topic with duplicate detection, you must configure the publish topology in both the producer and the consumer (it only needs to be configured once per bus instance, but if your producer is a separate bus instance, it would also need the configuration). The topic must also not already exist as it would not be updated once created in Azure.

To configure the publish topology:

```csharp
namespace DupeDetection
{
    public interface DupeCommand
    {
        string Value { get; }
    }
}
```

```csharp
var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Publish<DupeCommand>(x => x.EnableDuplicateDetection(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)));

    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("dupe", e =>
    {
        e.Consumer<DupeConsumer>();
    });
}
```

The consumer is normal (no special settings required).

```csharp
class DupeConsumer :
    IConsumer<DupeCommand>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<DupeCommand> context)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

> I've added a unit test to verify this behavior, and can confirm that when two messages with the same `MessageId` are published back-to-back, only a single message is delivered to the consumer.

Test log output:

```
10:53:15.641-D Create send transport: sb://masstransit-build.servicebus.windows.net/MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Tests.DupeDetection/DupeCommand
10:53:15.784-D Topic: MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Tests.DupeDetection/DupeCommand (dupe detect)
10:53:16.375-D SEND sb://masstransit-build.servicebus.windows.net/MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Tests.DupeDetection/DupeCommand dc3a0000-ebb8-e450-949c-08d8e8939c7f MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Tests.DupeDetection.DupeCommand
10:53:16.435-D SEND sb://masstransit-build.servicebus.windows.net/MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Tests.DupeDetection/DupeCommand dc3a0000-ebb8-e450-949c-08d8e8939c7f MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Tests.DupeDetection.DupeCommand
10:53:16.469-D RECEIVE sb://masstransit-build.servicebus.windows.net/MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Tests/input_queue dc3a0000-ebb8-e450-949c-08d8e8939c7f MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Tests.DupeDetection.DupeCommand MassTransit.IConsumer<MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Tests.DupeDetection.DupeCommand>(00:00:00.0017972)
```

You can see the `(dupe detect)` attribute shown on the topic declaration.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I should have made the question more specific.  Unfortunately I am not using DI.

Comment: Is there another way to generate the IBusRegistrationContext needed by the ConfigureEndpoints method? I'll take a look around the API and source code to see if I can satisfy it.

Comment: It doesn't matter for this case, it was just part of the example. It works equally well with containerless configuration.

Comment: In a containerless configuration the ConfigureEndpoints method still expects an IBusRegistrationContext parameter but one is not exposed anywhere that I can find. So this method is not usable.

Comment: I removed the container to avoid confusion in the answer.

Comment: Thank you Chris. When I had tried cfg.ReceiveEndpoint before it had created a Queue and not a Topic, but maybe I did not try it in combination with the cfg.Publish or I was doing the cfg.Publish after instead of before. So I will give this another look. I appreciate your patient assistance!

Comment: Does this still work for the current version of masstransit and azure service bus? are there any other ways to prevent duplicates now, if this does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I finally found. It does not rely on trying any of the ReceiveEndpoint or SubscriptionEndpoint configuration methods which never seemed to give me what I wanted.

```
IBusControl bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Publish<MembershipNotifications.MembershipSignupMessage>(configure =>
    {
        configure.EnableDuplicateDetection(_DuplicateDetectionWindow);
        configure.AutoDeleteOnIdle = _AutoDeleteOnIdle;
        configure.DefaultMessageTimeToLive = _MessageTimeToLive;
    });
}

await bus.Publish(new MessageTest());
```

Comment: You will still need to configure the same thing on the consumer side or you'll have conflicting topic configurations between the producer/consumer.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Chris. Yes, this project employs the Masstransit in Azure Functions solution on the consumer side.  The publish side is an older Asp.Net  Framework project.  Everything is up and running and working perfectly!